# How to make a variable of another file appear in heredocs of the wanted file?

Tags: php

I'm trying to make $count which is in cart.php appear in a heredocs of another file called component.php, both of these files can already communicate with each other.

here is the cart.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("php/CreateDb.php");
require_once("php/component.php");
$db = new CreateDb("Productdb2", "Producttb2",);
if (isset($_POST['remove'])) {
    if ($_GET['action'] == 'remove') {
        foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $value) {
            unset($_SESSION['cart']);
            if ($value["product_id"] == $_GET['id']) {
                /* echo "<script>alert('Product has been Removed...!')</script>"; */
                echo "<script>window.location = 'cart.php'</script>";
            }
        }
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Carrinho</title>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3da1a747b2.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="semantic/dist/semanticModificado.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="payment.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="cart.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container" id="navmobile" style="display: none">
        <img src="upload\felinefilogo.svg" style="margin-top: 1rem" height="100px" width="250px" alt="">
        <img src="upload\felinefi.svg" height="20px" width="62.5px" alt="">
        <nav class="navbar" style="padding: 0; margin-right: 16px; font-size: 1.4rem">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="index.php">Início</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">Sobre</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Contato</a></li>
                <li><?php include("php/header.php") ?></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar" id="navdesktop">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="imagem"><img src="upload\felinefihorizontalmedium.svg" height="100px" width="250px" alt="">
            </div>
            <ul class="nav" style="font-size: 1.4rem">
                <li><a href="index.php">Início</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">Sobre</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Contato</a></li>
                <li><?php require("php/header.php") ?></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <section class="section-aPayment">
        <div class="containerPayment">
            <div class="row" style="flex-wrap:nowrap" !important>
                <div class="col-75">
                    <br>
                    <h2 class="meuCarrinho">Meu carrinho</h2>
                    <br>
                    <?php
                    $total = 0;
                    if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
                        $product_id = array_column($_SESSION['cart'], 'product_id');
                        $result = $db->getData();
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                            foreach ($product_id as $id) {
                                if ($row['id'] == $id) {
                                    cartElement($row['product_image'], $row['product_name'], $row['product_price'], $row['id']);
                                    $total = $total + (float) $row['product_price'];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "<h1>Seu carrinho está vazio!</h1>";
                        ?>
                        <style type="text/css">
                            .subCoEsquerda4 {
                                display: none;
                            }

                            #hidethisDiv {
                                display: none;
                            }
                        </style>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-25">
                    <br>
                    <h2>Resumo da compra</h2>
                    <br>
                    <div class="containerResumo">
                        <div class="subCoEsquerda1">
                            <h3 class="esquerda">Itens</h3>
                            <h3 class="direita2">
                                <?php
                                if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
                                    $count  = count($_SESSION['cart']);
                                    echo "($count)";
                                } else {
                                    echo "(0 items)";
                                }
                                ?></h3>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <hr>
                        </div>
                        <div class="subCoDireita2">
                            <h3 class="esquerda">Desconto</h3>
                            <h3 class="direita2" id="hidethisDiv"> 50% </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <hr>
                        </div>
                        <div class="subCoEsquerda3">
                            <h3 class="esquerda">Valor total</h3>
                            <h3 class="direita2"><?php echo "$ " . number_format($total, 2); ?></h3>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="subCoEsquerda4">
                            <a href="payment.php"><button class="positive fluid ui button">Continuar</button></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.16/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
    <script src="semantic/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("input[name='expyear']").mask("00 / 00");
        $("input[name='zip']").mask("00000 - 000");
    </script>

    <script>
        //a condição surte efeito quando a página da reload ou aperta f5.
        $(document).ready(function() {
            if ($(this).width() < 500) {

                $('#navdesktop').hide();
                $('#navmobile').show();

            } else if ($(this).width() > 500) {

                $('#navmobile').hide();
                $('#navdesktop').show();

            }
        });

        //a condição surte efeito apenas quando mexe na "responsividade" da página.
        $(window).resize(function() {

            if ($(this).width() < 500) {

                $('#navdesktop').hide();
                $('#navmobile').show();

            } else if ($(this).width() > 500) {

                $('#navmobile').hide();
                $('#navdesktop').show();

            }

        });
    </script>

    <script>
        //aumentar e diminuir a quantidade dos itens (respectivamente)
        $(function() {
            $('#mais').on('click', function() {
                var $qty = $(this).closest('h1').find('.qty');
                var currentVal = parseInt($qty.val());
                if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
                    $qty.val(currentVal + 1);
                }
            });
            $('#menos').on('click', function() {
                var $qty = $(this).closest('h1').find('.qty');
                var currentVal = parseInt($qty.val());
                if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
                    $qty.val(currentVal - 1);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I wanna get the $count variable which is in cart.php and put it in the sole input value here:

```
<input class="qty" value="1" type="text" style="padding-right: 8px; padding-left: 12px; width: 34px;" maxlength="1" disabled="">
```

which is in this component.php file here:

```
<?php
function cartElement($productimg, $productname, $productprice, $productid)
{
    $element = <<< EOD
                <form action="cart.php?action=remove&id=$productid" method="post">
                    <div class="cartContainer">
                    <div class="sub-container">
                        <div class="imagem2"><img src="$productimg" alt=""></div>
                        <div class="conteudodaDiv">
                            <div class="title-e-icon">
                                <h3>$productname</h3> <button class="icon" name="remove"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                            </div>
                            <p>Ref: <span># D12-9970-014-39</span></p>
                            <p>Vendido por <a href="index.php">Felinefi</a> e entregue em até 8 dias úteis. </p>
                            <p>Frete GRÁTIS</p>
                            <p>Tamanho: <span>39 </span></p>
                            <p>Cor: <span>Preto</span> </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="eita">
                        <h1>Quantidade:&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <button type="button" class="ui circular button" id="menos"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="-5 -15 39 39">
                                    <path d="M12 2c5.514 0 10 4.486 10 10s-4.486 10-10 10-10-4.486-10-10 4.486-10 10-10zm0-2c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm6 13h-12v-2h12v2z" /></svg></button>
                            <div class="ui mini icon input focus">
                                <input class="qty" value="1" type="text" style="padding-right: 8px; padding-left: 12px; width: 34px;" maxlength="1" disabled="">
                            </div>
                            <button type="button" class="ui circular button" id="mais"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="-5 -15 39 39">
                                    <path d="M12 2c5.514 0 10 4.486 10 10s-4.486 10-10 10-10-4.486-10-10 4.486-10 10-10zm0-2c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm6 13h-5v5h-2v-5h-5v-2h5v-5h2v5h5v2z" /></svg></button>
                        </h1>
                        <div class="price">
                            <span>R$ 79.90</span><span>R$$productprice</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
                EOD;
    echo $element;
};
```

The whole point of that is to take the value that appears in "Itens"(items), as you can see in the picture

[image: cart.php]

and put it in the "quantidade"(quantity) input.

I Already tried to put the variable in the function cartElement() and then specified $count in the value but that didn't work.

How can I do that?

Comment: `$count` is just the length of a session variable. Can't you just do `$count = count($_SESSION['cart']);` in `component.php` as well?

Comment: i've read that this code block can't be inside a heredocs EOD

Comment: You don't put it inside the here-doc, you put it before the here-doc.

Comment: `$count = count($_SESSION['cart']); $element = <<< EOD`

Comment: Just that? so how am I going to associate the value?

I tried here and just that didn't work.

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work. Does `component.php` have `session_start();` at the beginning? Is something emptying the cart before it runs?

Comment: You could add another session variable. `$_SESSION['count'] = $count;` and then use `$_SESSION['count']` in `component.php`.

Comment: That kinda work, but how i'm going to make the value of $count appear in the input value="1"??? I need to replace the value 1 for something

Comment: `<input class="qty" value="$count" ...>` in the here-doc.

Comment: Also, when I increment the value in the input the value in itens doesn't update

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do. In `cart.h`, `$count` is the total number of items in the shopping cart. What does that have to do with the quantity of a particular item?

Comment: It's a single product store

Comment: If you want things to update without submitting the form you need to use JavaScript.

Comment: I used jquery to increase the quantity when I click the plus button, but it is not associated yet... I'm trying to find a way to associate the Items with the quantity..